# Why using planes instead of drones or other unmanned devices?

Tags: realism, top-gun-maverick

In [*Top Gun: Maverick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Gun:_Maverick) (2022), the plan is to use two fighter jets to breach and destroy a bunker.

The US forces know exactly the shape of the canyon that leads to the bunker, yet instead of sending unmanned devices (drones or another weapon) which could be programmed to follow the path without consideration for the acceleration hurting the capacities of the human pilots they decided for combat planes. Why?

Comment: I just don't think *"Top Gun: Stays back at base with a joystick controller & sends some toy planes on a mission"* would have had quite the same box-office pull.

Comment: My feeling is that a missile could not perform the manouvre required without being shot down by the anti-air defences but essentially it's probably for plot reasons.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/94703/15311)

Comment: Would you pay to go to cinema to see a drone operator sitting in front of several screens in a small room drinking a soda?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: Top Gun is not Avengers either. It is supposed to be based on a sensible story and why planes are used instead of drones is a relevant question (we daily hear about how drones are extraordinary). I was hoping for an in-world explanation that I would have missed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is information in the script which clarifies:

> The plant sits in a recess at the
> end of this valley. Said valley is
> GPS jammed and defended by an
> extensive radar array, serving a
> limited number of fifth generation
> fighters which, in turn, are backed
> up by a plentiful reserve of
> surplus aircraft; F-16s and even a
> few old F-14s
>
> The surface-to-air threat
> necessitates a low level, laser-
> guided strike, tailor made for the
> F-18. I figure two precision bombs
> minimum. Makes it four planes,
> flying in pairs.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that this clarifies the intent (but in reality a GPS is not needed, you could have had the weapon autonomous). But since the script says so, so be it :)

Comment: There is definitely some explanation like this in the film but I can't vouch for the exact words. It does try and explain the implausible fact that drones can't do it (but Tom Cruise can).